# yii2 Multi select dropdown remember selected

Tags: php, html, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a multi select dropdown menu, when I create the "project" it works just fine.

1. If I want to edit the created "project" it doesn't remember what I selected in the dropdown menu when the "project" was created.
2. It saves it to the database, it shows it is fine, but if you want to edit you need to select them again.

Is there anyway to make a auto-select where it selects them automatically according to the database? (I still want to be able to edit it, but I want them to be selected by default).

```
echo $form->field($model, 'company_id')->dropDownList($items_company, ['prompt' => 'Select Company','style' => 'width:400px;','onchange'=>'
            $.post("index.php?r=project/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
            $( "select#client" ).html( data );
            });
        ']);

if($model->client){
    echo $form->field($model, 'client')
        ->dropDownList(
            $items_client,
            ['id'=>'client','multiple' => true,'style' => 'width:400px;']
        );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix would be to just trigger the `change()` event of your `company_id` select box on document ready. Assuming the ID of your first select is `client`, here's the code:

```
$this->registerJs('$("select#client").trigger("change");', View::POS_READY);
```

However, I think you should try some widgets that handle dependent dropdowns, for example, [this one](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop).